# How to quote multiple paragraphs in amsart?

Tags: paragraphs, amsart, quotation

My goal is to quote two paragraphs using the `amsart` document style, with both paragraphs in the quotation being formatted in ordinary paragraph style, i.e. with the crown line indented.

The LaTeX Book on p. 26 says that the "quotation" environment is for quoting material that is entire paragraphs, and shows an example with the formatting I desire. The [AMS-LaTeX guide](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/%7Ehurder/math589/TeX/amshelp.pdf) does not describe quotations at all.

Testing shows that in `amsart` the "quotation" environment does not indent the first line of the quotation, but if the quotation contains an empty line the first line following it will be indented.

That is, the first paragraph is not paragraph-formatted but the second paragraph is paragraph-formatted. (The "quote" environment produces the same formatting, contra the LaTeX Book which says that "quote" is for non-paragraph-formatted text.)

Presumably there is a known way to do this but I haven't been able to find the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It's a deliberate choice of `amsart`

```
% amsart.cls, line 892:
\newenvironment{quotation}{\list{}{%
    \leftmargin3pc \listparindent\normalparindent
    \itemindent\z@
    \rightmargin\leftmargin \parsep\z@ \@plus\p@}%
  \item[]%
}{%
  \endlist
}
```

The instruction `\itemindent\z@` is what makes the first paragraph not to be indented.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\quotation}{\z@}{\normalparindent}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is the first paragraph and we want that it
is indented like every other paragraph. Some more
text just to see what happens.

\begin{quotation}
This is the first quoted paragraph and we want that it
is indented like every other paragraph. Some more
text just to see what happens.

This is the second quoted paragraph and we want that it
is indented like every other paragraph. Some more
text just to see what happens.
\end{quotation}

This is the final paragraph and we want that it
is indented like every other paragraph. Some more
text just to see what happens.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've made this change and for me it causes "quotation" to behave as described/like I want.

I've checked, and it does not cause the behavior of "quote" to change.  But you can get "quote" to behave like the LaTeX Book shows by separating the items inside "quote" with "\\[\baselineskip]" or "\\" rather than empty lines, as you would expect.

Comment: @user2864482 As far as I can see, `amsart` wants `quote` to do essentially the same as `quotation`.